# Finding and moving images without extensions between two directories

Tags: command

I have an old disorganized repository of files in a directory. I would like to move solely the images files to a new directory for archival purposes. The problem is that in this directory I have a mixture of multiple different types of files, including videos and movies. In addition, I have multiple types of images. Many of the images have no extension and I would like to move only the "jpeg" images to the new repository, so I can organize the jpeg files in a folder for its type.  How can I do this?

Comment: What is a "repository" in this case?

Comment: hi, it is a folder on my computer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `find` as follows:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file --mime-type "$0" | grep -q image/jpeg\$ && printf "$0\n"' {} \; -exec mv -t 'path_to_new_folder' {} +
```

This command will find jpeg files without extensions then move these files to a new folder.